# Setting private field on user control prevents changing 'Visible' from working

Tags: c#, asp.net

In a page, I have an event handler that sets 'Visible' to false on one control and true on another. Stepping through debug, I see that these values get set properly, and the control marked visible goes through OnPreRender while the control I have set to invisible does not. So all of that seems to be working as expected. However, when the request completes, the visibility has not changed at all on the page. I've tried setting the directly parent UpdatePanel to 'always' and have tried manually calling 'Update()' on it with no effect. Any clue as to what is going on here?

UPDATE:

I have found that it is only setting a private property on my user control that causes this whole thing to not work. I have included an example of that control and all of the places it references the private field.

Example:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsPostback)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.Control1.Visible = true;
    this.Control2.Visible = false;
}

protected void OnButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Control1.Visible = false;
    this.Control2.Visible = true;
    // this has desired results when it fires
}

protected void OnUserControlEventThatFiresAfterRowCommand (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Control2.SomeProp = this.GetSomeObject();

    this.Control1.Visible = false;
    this.Control2.Visible = true;
    // this does not have desired results, even though it does fire
}
```

And then in Control2:

```
private SomeClass privatefield;

public SomeClass SomeProp
{
    get
    {
        return this.privatefield;
    }
    set
    {
        this.PopulateFields(value);

        this.privatefield = value;
        // If I comment out this line it works!
    }
}

protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    object[] state = savedState as object[];

    base.LoadViewState(state[0]);
    this.Enabled = state[1] as bool? ?? true;
    this.SomeProp = state[2] as SomeClass;
    this.Visible = state[3] as bool? ?? true;
}

protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    return new object[]
    {
        base.SaveViewState(),
        this.Enabled,
        this.SomeProp,
        this.Visible
    };
}
```

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: I have added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out why by looking at the actual response body.

156|error|500|Error serializing value 'withheld class name' of type 'withheld class name'|

Why this error was not being thrown in debug is beyond me, but for anyone else reading this question looking for answers, look at your response bodies! It is because I was trying to put my instance of a class into Viewstate but that class was not marked with the Serializable attribute.